# Add external antenna to wireless repeater

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, routing

I would like to ask you two questions. To begin with, is it possible to add external antenna to my wireless WiFi repeater. Is there any way to attach pigtail or something that would let me plug in directional antenna with SMA port?

And other one is: which antenna connects to my router, and which one connects to my phone? Lower left or lower right?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you see the circles I have drawn below, that is where you can solder an rp-sma connector. The inner part is the male connection and the outer is the shielding.

[image: rp-sma location]

You cannot choose a specific antenna that connects to the phone and one that connects to the router. There is no way of knowing which is TX and which is RX.

I'd highly advise against this as you have no schematic nor can you read the resistance from the micro resisters that sit inline on the inner pole of the antenna. Any assumptions about what the optimal dBi should be is dangerous and could possibly lead to damaging your devices.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I've got one more question. You said that I cannot choose which antenna connects to specific device. Does that mean they keep swapping? If antenna x today connects to router and antenna z connects to phone after 2 days it could be the opposite way?

Comment: Thats such a touchy subject as we do not have anyway of knowing unless you contact the manufacturer. All you can do is use the same antenna for both connections.